# Passing R data.table column values to udf input argument in postgres

Tags: r, postgresql, user-defined-functions, rpostgresql

I have a udf in postgres that expects array as input argument. Example:

```
create or replace function vwap(prices numeric[], volume integer[])
```

I have the prices and volume stored in a R data.table.

```
dt <- data.table(prices = numeric(), volume = integer())
```

How do I use RPostgresql or any other postgres package to call the defined udf?

Comment: The example I have provided is a very basic example. I need to run simulations in postgres (pivotal greenplum MPP architecture) for which input arrays need to be passed in as arguments to postgres udf. These arrays are stored in R data.table. Hope that helps.

Comment: `DBI::dbWriteTable(con, "mytable", mydata[c("prices","volume")], create=TRUE)` to create a table (optionally temporary), then something like `DBI::dbGetQuery(con, "select vwap(prices, volume) from mytable")`. You might want to clean-up with `DBI::dbExecute(con, "drop table mytable")` or `DBI::dbExecute(con, "delete from mytable")` (both are assuming, of course, that you own the table and are happy discarding anything in it ... please don't do this cavalierly).